# What is the font used in this Horton Police Dept. badge?

Tags: font-identification

I need to know the name of the font that says Horton.

[image]

Comment: Hi Tammy, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. We have a collection of font identification resources [right here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/font-identification/info), and it is a good idea to try those first. Please let us know what you have tried without luck. Always good to show a little effort, and chances of getting a good answer increase. Please don't be discouraged, we know that using this site can be a learning curve. We *are* happy to have you!

Answer (score 2):

Not perfect but similar :

- Letraset-Crillee-CE-Bold-Italic
- PTICristeta-BoldItalic
- AddCityboy-Normal

take a look at this site for reference : http://www.whatfontis.com/AddCityboy-Normal.font?text=HORTN

look good to me....
hope it help !